# Wordpress Multisite on existing subdomain Installation

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, multisite

I have a fresh Wordpress install that I have put onto a temporary subdomain temp.example.com as I want to transfer in blog.example.com as part of a multisite on this install that will work with the main marketing site www.example.com.

However when I enable multisite and go to the network settings it is trying to create site1.temp.example.com.

How do I configure this so the sites it creates are temp.example.com and site2. example.com (without thesub-sub-domain) so I can transfer the existing sites into this. I already have live sites on the main example.com domain and so can't change the cname/a record for this.

TIA

Nick

Comment: then you have to put a subdomain to example.com like site1.example.com not for temp.example.com

Comment: Thanks @charankumar but I can't install this on example.com because it is being used.